# TintManager can not be find when update support Library from 23.0.1 to 23.2.0

Tags: android

Today my project cannot find the `TintManager` class when upgrade to support 23.2.0 .
  I can not find any answers in stackoverflow , Look the new `appCompant-support:23.2.0/TintResource` I find :

```
 AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(getContext(), ResId));
```

any other register? please tell me, Thank you!